How to query in multiple tables when can't use _TABLE_SUFFIX?
I tried query across multiple tables but _TABLE_SUFFIX doesn't work in my case.
I want caculate across multiple tables which is listed below:
01_2021, 01_2022, 01_2023, 01_2024, 02_2021, 02_2022, 02_2023, 02_2024, 03_2020, 03_2021, 03_2022, 03_2024, 04_2020, 04_2021, 04_2022, 04_2023, 04_2024, 05_2020, 05_2021, 05_2022, 05_2023, 05_2024, 06_2020, 06_2021, 06_2022, 06_2023, 06_2024, 07_2020, 07_2021, 07_2022, 08_2023, 08_2024, 09_2021, 09_2022, 09_2023, 10_2020,  ... 12_2020, 12_2021, 12_2022, 12_2023.  

File named by month, from 2020 April - 2024 August.
I want query by year. However, when I used _TABLE_SUFFIX:
create table `<data_set>.2021` as
select
  *,
  extract(time FROM started_at) as start_time,
  extract(day from started_at) as start_day,
  extract(month from started_at) as start_month,
  extract(year from started_at) as start_year,
  extract(dayofweek from started_at) as start_weekday,
  extract(time FROM ended_at) as end_time,
  extract(day from ended_at) as end_day,
  extract(month from ended_at) as end_month,
  extract(year from ended_at) as end_year,
  extract(dayofweek from ended_at) as end_weekday
from
  `<data_set>.*_2021`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '01' AND '12'

I expect to creat tables by years. However, above code got error Not found: Table <...*_2021> was not found in location asia-southest1
I guess it just works when have prefix (so it's suffix :v lol), because below code work. However, below code different from my original goal.
FROM
  `<data_set>.01_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2021' AND '2024'

I tried replace total file name with *
FROM
  `Cyclist_data.*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '01_2021' AND '12_2021'

However, I guess because BQ arrange file like picture. So it will across 01_2021, 01_2022, 03_2023... before 12_2021, I saw query results will contain data of 2024.


_TABLE_DATE_RANGE also doesn't work in this case. It got error Expected "," or "]" but got ":" evethough I follow instructions.
from
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([elemental-alloy-416508:Cyclist_data.], 
  TIMESTAMP('01_2021'), 
  TIMESTAMP('12_2021'))

Does have any solution for my case?
P/s: I have thought about change manually all files's name to 2021_01, but it will be last choice. Thanks so much for all answers!!

It feels like a query similar to:
FROM
  `<data_set>.*`
WHERE
  ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_2021')

should work.  This should include only tables that have names that end with "_2021".
If this does not work, please update the question with:

A listing of the names of the tables in your dataset
The exact SQL query you ran
The exact results of the query (including any warning or error messages)
What you expected that was distinct from the result obtained

References

Google SQL - ENDS_WITH


Your solution works T.T. I have also updated the question as suggested. Thanks for all.
